# C# MVC7 DNX5 MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Got a Noob question.  I am trying to write a C# MVC Application to connect to an MS SQL DB using the Entity Framework.  But I am getting the following error.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   HAPI.DNX 4.5.1, HAPI.DNX Core 5.0

My Code is as follows

## DB Context Class which flags no issues.

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Something.Models
{
    public class RulesDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Rules> Rules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

## Calling Class with errors on the Sql Statements highlighted in bold

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;


namespace Something.Models
{
    public class ReadRules
    {
        private RulesDbContext db = new RulesDbContext();
        private void Rules()
        {
            List<Rules> rulesMeta = db.Database.**SqlQuery**<Rules>("GetRuleMetaData @deviceID",
                                new **SqlParameter**("deviceID", deviceID)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2483